# Is Detect Hidden (level 5) required to open secret doors?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I am unclear from the tooltip of level 5 Detect Hidden if it's *required* for you to open secret doors, or just a useful aid in helping you find them.

[image]

I ask because I found 4 of 5 lorestones in the Gorguath runes. I could see the last one up above the room where you fight the Thresh, but couldn't figure out how to get to it. [Looking around online for the answer](http://www.ign.com/wikis/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/Gorguath), I saw that you apparently need to go through a secret door to get the one I'm missing. However, I've run around the dungeon like crazy trying to interact with walls and such hoping I'd be able to open a secret door, but have had no luck, making me wonder if it's even possible to open the secret door without the skill.

Comment: If you have tier 2 on the Jack of All Trades destiny, it gives you +1 to your skills, so you can have level 5 detect without spending the skill point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do need it.

You are unable to interact with Hidden Doors until you are at least level 5 in Detect Hidden.