# Where are the Lorestones in Gorguath?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I completed The Song of Sir Sagrell quest in Reckoning and did a relatively thorough search of Gorguath but I can only find four of the Lorestones. Is one in a hidden location, or have I just missed it? If the latter, map markers for all the Lorestones would be handy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's behind a hidden door, which you will need the fifth skill in "Detect Hidden" in order to find ([Explained here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50191/is-detect-hidden-level-5-required-to-open-secret-doors)).

[image]